# what does this useState function do and how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to understand the working of useState hook of react but i am not able to understand how does it do that what it do
for example
in this JavaScript code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

 function onClick()
  {setCount(2)
   }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{0}</p>
      <button onClick={onclick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

useState is initialized with a value of 0 and in return we get a variable with its initial value and function to update that value.

Now how does this function find value 0 in whole document and return the function to update that value (how does it find that value) and also how does the setCount function update that 0 to 2 how does it finds which 0 we are considering.

Comment: `how does this function find value 0 in whole document` What does this mean?

Comment: @ksav I mean how does useState() function finds the initial value in whole JavaScript file how does it know which 0(zero) are we taking about and which value we want to update using setCount

Comment: Check out [this mental model](https://medium.com/@ryardley/react-hooks-not-magic-just-arrays-cd4f1857236e) of state hooks and [this KCD article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-implement-usestate-with-usereducer); it might help you conceptually understand what's going on under the hood

Comment: It doesn't _find_ the initial value anywhere. It is explicitly passed `0` as the initial value here - `useState(0)`.

Comment: Also I think you probably meant `<p>{count}</p>`; if you didn't I think there are some React basics you may need to brush up on - highly recommend [the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

`useState` is a React Hook. We call it inside a function component to add some local state to that component.

- The only argument of `useState` is the initial value.
- `useState` returns a pair: the current value and a function that lets us update the value with a new value.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Example() {
  // Declare a new piece of state with an initial value of 0
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  // value - the current value
  // setValue - the function used to update the value

  return (
    <div>
      <p>current value: {value}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}>Add 1 to value</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit epic-clarke-ryfky]

Comment: my jQuery/vanilla brain would say to write the onclick function as so: 
`<button onClick={setValue(value + 1)}>Add 1 to value</button>`
Why does setValue have to be embedded in a second, unnamed function?

Comment: In JSX, you need to pass a function as the event handler. `setValue(value + 1)` is not a function, it is the execution of a function.  See https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Thanks for answering but I find reactjs docs to read more academic and I did not get a CS degree. [This explanation](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/react-why-use-anonymous-function-for-event-handler/432515/3) was a lot more straightforward. I understand the concept now. Basically I'm writing the function within the onClick event instead of naming the function then adding it in like I would in vanilla.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from creating a function in the component body (or anywhere, really) and passing the reference to that function in the `onClick` eg https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-matsumoto-82dfyx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ah, many thanks for this demo. I was trying to do something like that on my own but I was trying to pass through the value const as a parameter and react didnt like it.

Answer (score 0):

`useState` is a `Hook` that allows to have a state variables in a functional component. The function accepts an initial state and returns a variable with the current state and another function to update this value.

In the following code at this line `const [count, setCount] = useState(0);` is using destructuring to get the arguments of the `useState` . The first argument is the initial value and second one is a function to update the initial value. The initial value can be of any data type. By convention the name of the function that is the second argument starts with `set`.Here the value of `count` is initially set to 0.

In this code on click of the button the `onclick` function is called which in turns called the `setState` which updates the value of the `count`. `React Hooks` are to be used inside the functional component only

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function onclick() {
    setCount(count + 2);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        // rendering value of count
        <p>{count}</p>
        <button onClick={onclick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5sg8dq)